# Unable to get file or directory click on camera?

Tags: android, retrofit, image-gallery, android-camera-intent

I am implementing a code for camera and gallery intent, when i click on gallery
it works perfectly and image uplaod on the server. But when i click on camera i get a path  and when i upload it show error like "no such file or directory".after all code check i cannot find error, please suggest me Code is here:-

Activity code is:-

```
public class Preception_upload_only extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView imageView;
private String userChoosenTask;
private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
LinearLayout mainLayout;
Bitmap bitmap;
Uri gelleryUri,fileUri,ur;
Button submit;
String user_id,imagepath;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
TypedFile avtarfile=null;
RadioButton radioButton;
ProgressBar progressBar;

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preception_upload_only);

    user_id = com.hp.medwaala.Util.M.getNumber(getApplicationContext());
    FINDVIEWBYID();
    CLICKLISTINER();
}

private void FINDVIEWBYID() {

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upload_prection_only_icon);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout_only);
    radioGroup= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_selected);
    submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadprecption_button);
    progressBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_uploadprescription);
}

private void CLICKLISTINER() {

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            String getext= (String) radioButton.getText();

            avtarfile = new TypedFile("image/*", new File(imagepath));

            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(AppConst.MAIN).build();
            UsersAPI uploadpreception = restAdapter.create(UsersAPI.class);

            uploadpreception.uploadpreception(user_id, getext, avtarfile, avtarfile, avtarfile, avtarfile, new Callback<Upload_preception>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Upload_preception upload_preception, Response response) {

                    String sucessss=upload_preception.getSuccess();

                    if (sucessss.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        Toast.makeText(Preception_upload_only.this, "Customer care Will call you in 24 hours thanks ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(Preception_upload_only.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                                                }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(Preception_upload_only.this, "Failureee"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            });



        }
    });


    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            selectImage();
        }

                });
}

private void selectImage() {

    final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Preception_upload_only.this,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle1);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(Preception_upload_only.this);

            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                if (result)
                    cameraIntent();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                if (result)
                    galleryIntent();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);
}

private void cameraIntent() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Preception_upload_only.this,
            "com.hp.medwaala.FileProvider",
            getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE));
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}


private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.Dope/");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {

            return null;
        }
    }

    File mediaFile;
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "IMG_" + new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString() + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return mediaFile;
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            previewCapturedImage();
            onCaptureImageResult(bitmap);
            getimage();
        }
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            gelleryUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(FilePath.getPath(Preception_upload_only.this, data.getData())));
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(gelleryUri);


            getimage();
        }
    }
}


private void previewCapturedImage() {

    try {

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        InputStream ims = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);


    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Bitmap mUri) {


    RelativeLayout r1 = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    r1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 400));

    ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    img.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    img.setTag(mUri);

    img.setImageBitmap(mUri);
    ImageView cross = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    cross.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    cross.setClickable(true);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) cross.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    cross.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross_icon);
    cross.setId('1');
    cross.setOnClickListener(this);
    r1.addView(img);
    r1.addView(cross);

    mainLayout.addView(r1);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Uri mUri) {


    RelativeLayout r1 = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    r1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 400));
    ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    img.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

    img.setTag(mUri);

    img.setImageURI(mUri);

    ImageView cross = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    cross.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    cross.setClickable(true);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) cross.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    cross.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross_icon);
    cross.setId('1');
    cross.setOnClickListener(this);
    r1.addView(img);
    r1.addView(cross);

    mainLayout.addView(r1);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == '1') {
        LinearLayout linearParent = (LinearLayout) v.getParent().getParent();
        RelativeLayout linearChild = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
        linearParent.removeView(linearChild);


    }
}

private void getimage() {


    RelativeLayout ra =(RelativeLayout) mainLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int childCount = ra.getChildCount();
    List<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {

        ImageView imG = (ImageView)ra.getChildAt(0);
        String path =  imG.getTag().toString();


        if(imG.getTag().toString().contains("Bitmap"))
        {
            Bitmap path1 = (Bitmap)imG.getTag();
            ur=  getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),path1);
        }
        else {
            ur =(Uri)imG.getTag();
        }

        imagepath=ur.toString();
        mStrings.add(ur.toString());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: `But when i click on camera i get a path`. No. Then a camera app will be started.  If the user takes a picture then the camera app will save a jpg to `fileUri`. And onActivityResult() will be invoked.

Comment: `onCaptureImageResult(Bitmap mUri)`. If you want to make it yourself difficult then name a Bitmap mUri indeed.

Comment: There is no code that tries to upload something.

Comment: Image upload successfully when i get from gallery.. but when i click from camera it shows name of a image but.i cannot get a accurate path.of camera image

Comment: Your accurate path is your `fileUri`.

Comment: @greenapps i get a path from fileuri: is content:// "my package name"/media/external/images/"imagename" .....  Its show error while uploading  i want a storage path.

Comment: No need for a different path. Just use that uri, that content scheme, to open an InputStream. Then read from the stream as you did from a FileInputStream.

Comment: You are not reading this site are you? Your problem and the solution can be found every week.